# shortcut to start script (Excel VBA Drop Down List via Data Validation)

Tags: excel, vba

Implemented a VBA script (not created by me) to be able to select multiple words from a controlled term list entered into specific cells of an EXCEL spreadsheet. This is based on data validation lists.

The **problems** are the following:

- If I use data validation in columns for which I don't want to use the script (data validation is needed here, so I can add comments for the user when the cell is selected; comment boxes don't help), overwriting of terms or in-cell deleting doesn't work properly.
  So I thought I could refine the script to only work in separate cells/columns. How can I do that?
- I'd like to have a shortcut to start the script, rather than (or additional to) a double click.

Any suggestions how to change the code to solve these issuese would be highly appreciated!

This is the code used:

```
   Option Explicit
' ...
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lType As Long
Dim strList As String
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
   lType = Target.Validation.Type
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If lType = 3 Then
  'if the cell contains a data validation list
   Cancel = True
   strList = Target.Validation.Formula1
   strList = Right(strList, Len(strList) - 1)
   strDVList = strList
   frmDVList.Show
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strSep As String
strSep = ", "
  Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else

  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
   If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
   Else
         If oldVal = "" Then
            Target.Value = newVal
         Else
            Target.Value = oldVal & strSep & newVal
         End If
    End If

End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked more than one question.
This is not a complete answer to all your questions.

Let's say you want to limit the activity to changes to only columns **A** or **B**.

Right after:

```
strSep = ", "
```

include a line like:

```
If Intersect(Target,Range("A:B")) is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Modify this line to limit activity to your columns of interest.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly fine, changed the 2nd _if_ to _is_